# Call method to generate arguments in ruby works in 1.8.7 but not 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-1.9.3

This is something that I had working in ruby 1.8.7, but no longer works in 1.9.3, and I am not sure what changes make this fail.

Previously, I had something like this

```
myFunction(submitArgs())
```

where submitArgs was a helper method that could be called with some options

```
def submitArgs(args={})
  #Some logic/manipulations
  ["Text", args]
end
```

Then myFunction would be called with the first argument "Text", and the second a hash. Now in 1.9.3, it is being called with "Text {}" all as one big string.

Does anyone know what change was made between the ruby versions that causes this, and if there is an alternative to returning an array of arguments in 1.9.3?

Comment: looks ok to me, maybe try `"Text", args`, or check out this response http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725500/how-does-ruby-return-two-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change required (in github notation):

```
- myFunction(submitArgs())
+ myFunction(*submitArgs)
```

The reason that [I assume] `myFunction` is declared taking two arguments:

```
def myFunction a1, a2
```

Hence the array must be splatted before passing to it. I wonder how that worked in `1.8`.

Comment: Didn't seem to like that either. Same issue.

Also, myFunction's second argument is optional.

Comment: It's actually just the rails form submit helper>> [here](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/submit)

Comment: Splatting does work.. I was editing the wrong file the first time i tried it. Thanks!