# Conditional assignment from a function with multiple return values in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, list, methods, variable-assignment

Is there a way to use the conditional assignment operator (||=) to assign to a particular value from a function that returns multiple values?

For example, I've seen this pattern a lot:

```
def foo
  'hello'
end

def bar
  @bar ||= foo
end
```

This works great if `foo` returns a single value. What about if foo returns two values, and I only want to assign bar to the first value?

```
def foo
  return 'hello', 'world'
end

def bar
  @bar ||= foo
end

# How to set bar = 'hello' ?
```

Is there some way to conditionally assign to only the first value returned? If not -- what would be the idiomatic way to set the `bar` instance variable to 'hello'?

(EDITED: fixed typo in foo in second example -- forgot to explicitly return.)

Comment: "What about if foo returns two values" It doesn’t. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725500/how-does-ruby-return-two-values to understand your own code.

Comment: `@bar ||= foo.first`

Comment: @matt thanks for catching that typo -- edited to correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby doesn't support multiple return values. It's simply syntax sugar for returning a list. Hence, the following works.

```
@bar ||= foo[0]
```

Comment: Do you mean "syntax sugar for returning an [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html)?" There is no such thing as a "list" in Ruby.